# Getting fatal error in flutter everytime i want to run it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My code was working properly last night then i decided to add Firebase to it and then it didn't worked at all.
I don't know what is wrong with my code.
This is the error i get :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28597): Process: com.example.ecommerce_app, PID: 28597
E/AndroidRuntime(28597): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ecommerce_app/com.armin.ecommerce_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.armin.ecommerce_app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~GUVMl_slVht6DSUkIqmUiA==/com.example.ecommerce_app-FxXMbI2cwIzxPOxOK9ifTA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~GUVMl_slVht6DSUkIqmUiA==/com.example.ecommerce_app-FxXMbI2cwIzxPOxOK9ifTA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~GUVMl_slVht6DSUkIqmUiA==/com.example.ecommerce_app-FxXMbI2cwIzxPOxOK9ifTA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ecommerce_app/com.armin.ecommerce_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.armin.ecommerce_app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~GUVMl_slVht6DSUkIqmUiA==/com.example.ecommerce_app-FxXMbI2cwIzxPOxOK9ifTA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~GUVMl_slVht6DSUkIqmUiA==/com.example.ecommerce_app-FxXMbI2cwIzxPOxOK9ifTA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~GUVMl_slVht6DSUkIqmUiA==/com.example.ecommerce_app-FxXMbI2cwIzxPOxOK9ifTA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]

Here is my main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Shop(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

if any else data needed to fix it please let me know.

I tried to remove the whole Firebase packages but it didn't worked.
I have no idea what's wrong with it

Comment: That error doesn't look like it has anything to do with Firebase.  The error is saying that Android can't find the class called "com.armin.ecommerce_app.MainActivity".

Comment: Oh ok so i'll remove firebase tag